# pyspark add new nested array to existing json file

Tags: json, hadoop, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I'm new in Spark and have a big problem, which I can't handle, even after hours of searching...
I have a jsonFile which looks like this:

```
root
 |-- dialogueData: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- dialogueID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- dialogueLength: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- speakerChanges: long (nullable = true)
 |-- snippetlist: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- confidence: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- length: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- role: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- snippetID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- transcription: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- wordCount: long (nullable = true)
```

My program does sentiment analysis and returns a dataframe column with predictions (1.0, 0.0, -1.0 etc) and also returns some values like average.
Now my problem:

I want to do two things:

1. I want to add my for example average value to the first struct "dialogeData"
2. I want to add my whole column to the array "snippetlist" as a new struct "sentiment", so that for each snippet in the array the correct sentiment appears.

Is that possible? I really dont find any good things about that case, so I really hope somebody can help me.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

First, before any other means to add, you would need to do a join so the elements you want to add are in new columns added to the original dataframe.
In any case once you have the relevant dataframe you can write it to json

To create the relevant dataframe you have several options:

The first option (which is easiest if you know scala) is to use scala in which case you can use the dataset API by creating a case class representing the original and target values and converting accordingly (not pretty).

The second option is to convert to RDD and use map to add the relevant data. This would probably be pretty ugly and inefficient.

The third option is to use to_json to convert the entire record to json stringYou can then write a UDF which converts the string to a json of the target (recieve the additional input, convert json to dictionary, update the dictionary and convert back to json). The resulting string can then be converted back to dataframe info by using the from_json function.

The fourth option would be to use dataframe options. The idea is that you can flatten a struct by using select("structName.*") and then you can recreated it using struct(col1, col2, ...).

To add an element to the array you would first need to posexplode it (this would create a row from each element in the array having one column for the position and one for the value), then flatten it, then add the element (by using the getItem function to get the relevant position) and convert back to struct and collect_list.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the fast answer.
I forogt to mention that I use pyspark...
Hm, your last approach sounds very good. Can you explain me "posexplode", or is it just the normal "explode" function? Can you maybe provide a little bit of code example? I am very new in this topic and very confused...

Comment: just take a look at https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.posexplode it already has a good example.

Comment: Okay, I now have my DF like I want it. This array now represents the above mentioned "snippetlist" array. how can I practically take this back in my existing jsonFile?

Comment: You can do df.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").json(filename), however I wouldn't do it this way. First if you write just one file with everything it (by definition) not parallel so if the file is large it can cause issues. Also as a good practice I don't like overwrite because if something goes wrong you can lose everything. I would save to a different location.

Comment: in the end we want a Json File that contains everything, so when I create a new Json file, I have to create a "Json Array" from my mentioned DataFrame so that I get the structure of Json I posted in my question, but now with entry "sentiment" added. Do you know how I can do that?

Comment: @pshustle How many records do you have (in the output dataframe)?

Comment: What do you mean with records? And please red my edit in the comment above your question

Comment: Is there any way to transform rows of a DF in an array so that every row represents an array element of my mentioned snippetlist array for my json file?

Comment: If the size of your data is small enough to fit in the driver you can do df.withColumn("str", to_json(all relevant columns)).select("str").collect().map(r => r.getString(0)) to get an array of strings where each string represents the json for that row. Then you can use non spark code to do whatever you want with it.

Comment: the code is scala, right? I modified it in pyspark code like this:

df2.withColumn("str", toJSON("prediction","sentiment")).select("str").collect().map(lambda r: r.getString(0)) 
but this doesnt work , the program claims that toJSON isnt defined...

Comment: it is to_json (in pyspark.sql.functions) and you extract the string from row by row('column name') in python

Comment: from_json and to_json are spark 2.1. You would have to extract the elements from the row manually...

Comment: Hm Yeah, I am using spark 1.6..is there any good way to do..?

Comment: @pshustle The only way I can think of doing it in spark 1.6 is to do a manual UDF which gets all the columns and builds the string manually.

Comment: @pshustle probably, however, I can't think of an efficient way to do it in pyspark with spark 1.6.